# Why does this work for $ i^{2i} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm finding the principal value of  $$ i^{2i} $$

And I know it's solved like this:

$$ (e^{ i\pi /2})^{2i} $$

$$ e^{ i^{2} \pi} $$

$$ e^{- \pi} $$

I understand the process but I don't understand for example where does the $ i $ in $ 2i $ go?

Is this some kind of a property of Euler's number? if so please explain to me.

Comment: Hint: what is $i^2$? and do you know what $(a^b)^c$ equals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\bigl(e^{i\pi /2}\bigr)^{2i} = e^{(i\pi /2) \cdot 2i}  = e^{i^2\pi}.$$

This is just an application of the exponent laws. Don't overthink it!

Answer (score 2):

The $i$ in $2i$ was combined with the $i$ inside the parentheses. Hence, you got $$i\cdot i = i^2$$ which is due to exponent laws. More applied to your case:
$$(e^{ i\pi /2})^{2i}=e^{i \cdot i \cdot \pi}=e^{i^2\cdot \pi}.$$

Comment: you missed a 2.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that
$i = e^{\pi i/2+2\pi i k}
=e^{\pi i(\frac12+2k)}
$
for any integer $k$,
since $e^{2 \pi i k} = 1$.
$k=0$ gives the usual principal value.

Therefore,
$i^{2i}
=(e^{\pi i(\frac12+2k)})^{2i}
=e^{2\pi i^2(\frac12+2k)}
=e^{-2\pi (\frac12+2k)}
=e^{-\pi (1+4k)}
$.
So, 
thanks to the joy of 
infinite valued complex logarithms,
your expression has an infinite number of
distinct values.

Note that,
for large negative $k$,
the value is quite large.